# current page width inconsistent

Tags: html, css, navbar, highlight

I have a "current" class which highlights the current page. And it works as far as highlighting the current page. With the padding I've added the highlighted area covers the a-element and go towards the top of the page which is what I want it to do. But each highlighted area is the width of the a-element and since each a-element has a different number of characters within, the widths are inconsistent.

To correct this I gave the a-element a `display: block`. This correction did give a consistent width, but now the highlighted area goes down towards the page as opposed to towards the top of the page as I wanted it.

How can I get a consistent width of highlighted area to go up towards the top of the page?

```css
nav {
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.top-nav {
  width: 785px;
  color: dimgrey;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-nav li {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.top-nav a {
  color: dimgrey;
  width: 150px;
}

.current {
  padding: 150px 0px 5px 0px;
  background-color: #fab938;
  color: white;
}

span.fa-bath {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fab938;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
    <li><a href="o-que-fazemos.html">O Que Fazemos?</a></li>
    <li><span class="fa fa-bath"></span></li>
    <li><a href="donations.html">Donations</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" class="current">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the way you build you nav.
Instead of using a float use a inline-block on the LI.
Next to that you can use vertical-align: middle; to align the items from the middle or use top/bottom.
also your nav container is not fitting the size of the 5 Li you are using.

https://jsfiddle.net/wyrscn48/1/

```
nav {
    margin: 100px auto; } 

.top-nav {
    width: 935px;
    color: dimgrey;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;

     }

.top-nav li {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

.top-nav a {
    color: dimgrey; 
    width: 150px; }

.current {
    background-color: #fab938;
    color: white; }

span.fa-bath {
    font-size: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fab938; 
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. And I'll take the inline-block into consideration. But are these preventing the "current" class from working as I described above?